# Import avj in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an application and a library. The library uses the "ajv" package.

The problem is that in my library I can import `Ajv` form the package without using curly braces

```js
import Ajv from "ajv";
```

accoring to the docs ("Getting started" section on https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv). But when I install my library in the application then I get the error saying that there is no default export in the "ajv" package. And that's true (https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/lib/ajv.d.ts).

So why can I use the mentioned above import syntax? And why there is a different behavior in the library and in the application?

In `package.json`:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.12.0"
  }
  ...
```

Let me know if you need more details about my config (like `package.json` or `tsconfig.json`)

Comment: Did you enable in your `tsconfig.json` the `esModuleInterop` flag?

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti Yes - it's enable in the library and disabled in the application. I understand that I need to enable it in both? Could it break something?
And what exactly happens in the case of the ajv package based on the `ajv.d.ts` file? What happens when I do `import Ajv from "ajv"`? How to create `Ajv` object with the `esModuleInterop` disabled?